# How to fix plotly graph size in dash web application

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to fix a graph size in a dash application, so that it is the desired size and that it doesn't change when resizing the browser page.

The code for my graph and dash application is as such:

```
distplot = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=50000, show_hist=False)

distplot = distplot.update_layout(
        title_text='Kernel Density Plot of House Price Data',
        title_x=0.5,
        xaxis_showgrid=False,
        yaxis_showgrid=False,
        hoverlabel=dict(font_size=10, bgcolor='rgb(69, 95, 154)'),
        legend=dict(title='Year of data',
                    x=1,
                    y=1,
                    traceorder='normal',
                    xanchor = 'auto')
)


#Dash application

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

##Creating Dash server ##
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions=True



url_bar_and_content_div = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content', style={'font': 'Georgia, sans-serif'})
                                ]
)

layout_index = html.Div([
    html.H1('Webpage Information', style={'textAlign': 'center'}),

    html.H2('Distplot', style={'font-size': '40px'}),

    html.Br(),

    dcc.Graph(id='distplot', figure=distplot),

],
    style={'margin-top': '20px', 'margin-bottom': '20px',
            'margin-right': '80px',  'margin-left': '80px'}
)


## Creating HTML style ##
# index layout
app.layout = url_bar_and_content_div

# "complete" layout
app.validation_layout = html.Div([
    url_bar_and_content_div,
    layout_index
])
# Index callbacks
@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
          [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    return layout_index

## Run ##
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I have tried several methods to achieve this, firstly putting the graph in it's own `html.Div()` and using `style{'height' : '700', 'width' : '700' }` but it hasn't worked. I have tried using `style` directly to the `dcc.Graph` object but this has also not worked.

Does anyone know how I would go about this? Thanks

EDIT
I can now properly set the size of the graph height using `height=700` in the `.update_layout()` method. However when resizing my browsing window, the graph rescales and changes size incorrecty to browser window size.

If anyone knows how to do this, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try including the width and height arguments inside the graph create method.

```
distplot = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=50000, 
show_hist=False, width=700, height=700)
```